# How to pass a function to a url in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to call a function to open a lightbox when someone clicks a link that create.  I have seen this done before but do not recall how something like:

```
google.com:javascript(openWindow())
```

does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: A good word to search for more information on this topic is "bookmarklet".

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript:openWindow()
```

is a URL that most browsers interpret as invoking the `openWindow()` function and treating the result coerced to a string as the result of loading the URL.

See [HTML5 6.1.5 The javascript: URL scheme](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#javascript-protocol) for more detail.

Comment: more specifically you'd write `javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com/');`

Comment: What I am trying to do is have the function called on the page.  I will give an example.

Comment: @jnolte, When should the function be called?  As the page loads or as a link or button is clicked?  If the latter, then James McCormack has answered your question.

Comment: I am looking to call it when the page loads but via a parameter in the url.  I want a lighbox function to open ONLY when the person clicks the link I provide. so essentially i am looking to pass the function into the url via a parameter.  I am quite sure this is possible but do not know how.

Comment: You could encode the function using `encodeURIComponent()`, send it in the querystring, and then `eval()` it on the target page if the querystring parameter is detected. This does feel quite hacky though, and I don't recommend the approach. It would be better to just pass a querystring parameter to cause a function on the target page to run, possibly using the querystring parameter as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

you might be referring to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BYnLB/)

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clickMe(){
            //your code here to call lightbox and etc.
            alert('test');
        }
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:clickMe()">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
<a href="#" onclick="yourOpenLightboxFunction(); return false;" />
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245868/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-methods-of-putting-javascript-code-i) gives more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be [BookMark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), you can bookmark to quickly run JavaScript functions from your address bar.

Answer (score 0):

The following code ended up being what helped me to complete the task. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383304/how-to-construct-a-url-to-open-a-page-with-jquery-lightbox-plugin-colorbox)

```
var url = document.location.href;
if(url.search(/\?lightbox/i) !== -1){
    //run function here

}
```